# Integral of inverse of a function

Tags: calculus-of-variations

The following question remain open and requests further research given function hypothesis.

Is it possible to  obtain a closed expression to the inverse of a function integral.

$\int_{0}^t \frac{1}{f(\tau)} d \tau = g(t) - g(0)$

Above the corresponding function is g(t). I thank in advance.

Comment: So , you are asking for an integral representation for the functional inverse of the integral of a given function ? Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(\tau):=\dfrac{1}{e^{-\tau^2}}$, the integral you get can not be expressed by means of usual functions. You can just get an expression with the error function $\mathrm{erf}$.

Comment: Erf is the closed function whose properties are known. The indefinite form for the integral of $e^{x^2}$ and $e^{-x^2}$ holds a relation: the first is -0.5 sqrt(pi) i erf(ix), the second 0.5 sqrt(pi) erf(x). My question is if there is a generic expression for all functions.